# Node.js connection with Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect mongo db with node js using Mongoos;
I installed mongoose package using bash (npm install mongoose)
when I tried running the application nothing happen and bash will be as in the attached picture [git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA7Ta.png) .

**app2.js code:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Comment: Well, your application doesn't do anything with that connection. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you have defined your model schema in the models folder, say 'cake.js' below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    days: {type: String, required: true},
    opening: String,
    closing: String,
    closed: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
    }
   });
const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required:true,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
        },
        reviewText: String,
        createdOn: {
            type: Date, 
            default: Date.now}
       });
const cakeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: {
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    address: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        'default':0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
qualities: [String], 
openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
reviews: [reviewSchema]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cake', cakeSchema);
```

You'll need to create a 'db.js' file in the same models folder that you will use to 'connect mongo db with node js using Mongoose' as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const readLine = require('readline');

let dbURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/CandyCakes';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  dbURL = process.env.DB_HOST || process.env.MONGODB_URI;
}

const connect = () => {
  setTimeout(() => mongoose.connect(dbURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }), 1000);
}

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('connected');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
  console.log('error: ' + err);
  return connect();
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
  console.log('disconnected');
});

if (process.platform === 'win32') {
  const rl = readLine.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.on ('SIGINT', () => {
    process.emit("SIGINT");
  });
}

const gracefulShutdown = (msg, callback) => {
  mongoose.connection.close( () => {
    console.log(`Mongoose disconnected through ${msg}`);
    callback();
  });
};

process.once('SIGUSR2', () => {
  gracefulShutdown('nodemon restart', () => {
    process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
  });
});
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  gracefulShutdown('app termination', () => {
    process.exit(0);
  });
});

connect();

require('./cakes');
```

Please make your MongoDB database is properly configured. With this connection, your database is ready to accept models.